# Huawei HG8245H, can't read some system files

Tags: firmware, linux

I have modem Echolife HG8245H (V3R016C10S150). I'm using telnet to connect it. I need to read some files from this modem. There's a shell mode I can enter, but it is nerfed badly:

```
SU_WAP>shell

BusyBox v1.18.4 (2016-10-11 19:35:35 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

profile close core dump  
WAP(Dopra Linux) # ?  
exit  
getcustominfo.sh  
restorehwmode.sh
```

These are all commands I can do in this mode. There is another way to look at the directories:

```
SU_WAP>wap list path /    
bin  
boot  
dev  
etc  
html  
lib  
libexec  
linuxrc  
mnt  
proc  
root  
sbin  
share  
sys  
tmp  
uer   
usr  
var
```

It works like 'ls'. But I can not read any file:

```
SU_WAP>wap list path /var/wifi.txt  
/var/wifi.txt  
success!
```

Commands like 'cat' aren't working. Does anybody know is there any way to read these files if you're connecting modem through telnet? Maybe this is not possible with this firmware?
Thank you:)

Comment: Why is `cat` not working? The command doesn't exist or doesn't work? Are there other commands that can open files? Maybe you could just dump the storage device that holds the firmware and analyze it from somewhere else.

Comment: Command is just not allowed. 'Exit', 'getcustominfo.sh', 'restorehwmode.sh' - that's all I can do in shell mode. Probably it's because of firmware. Analyzing the firmware is a good idea, maybe I can find some answers I'm looking for. I'll try it, thank you.

Comment: Btw thank you for editing my post, it looks much better now:)

Comment: Just for a sanity check, does `?` return the same output as `help`, from busybox?

Comment: Yeah it actually does. I showed it in my first post. If I type 'help' - BusyBox says that it doesn't know what 'help' is:D

Comment: One more question: what tools are you using to get firmware file from modem?

Comment: Well if you had any shell commands like `dd`, you could read the raw device. Or, use hardware hacking to dump e.g. flash chip or gain a full shell that way.

Comment: Thank you one more time)

Comment: @HE9CbITb do have access to download config backup file ?

Comment: @Vido yes I do.

Comment: @HE9CbITb can you save that page where it says `download configuration file` and `html/management/cfgfileroot.asp` and send it to me ? Do you have discord ?

Comment: My first thought would be to run `list path /bin/` and see what tools are available.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SU_WAP>display file /var/wifi.txt
```

Echolife HG8245W5-6T shell block

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Could you provide some context and perhaps a source for the information?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. System returns an error: "The directory or file is wrong!" I tried to open different files - all the same. But thanks for reporting:)

Comment: I also have HG8245H and busybox does not work for me, nor the display file

Comment: @Vido seems like busybox is nerfed by the firmware:(